# Opening a WebView using Coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, webview, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to open a WebView from my BottomNavBar using Coroutines, but I am getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was
>   called on thread 'DefaultDispatcher-worker-1'. All WebView methods
>   must be called on the same thread.

My code looks like the following:

```
class WebViewFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        openWebView()
    }

    private suspend fun showWebView(){
        if(webView != null){

            webView!!.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            webView!!.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

            val webSettings = webView!!.settings
            webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            webView!!.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")

            webView!!.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient(){
                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                }

                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun openWebView(){
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
            showWebView()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a best approach to achieve this? And can WebViews be loaded on another thread rather the UI thread?

Thanks :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dispatchers.Default` uses a thread pool under the hood, and as the exception is telling you the `WebView` expects to have its methods called from the same `Thread`, the UI `Thread` in this case.

Also, per the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) `runBlocking` should only be used by main functions and tests as it blocks the caller `Thread` until the coroutine completes.

> And can WebViews be loaded on another thread rather the UI thread?

No, `WebView` methods should be called from the UI `Thread`